# Running away from a 5 euro fine

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, cipher

Scenario:

It is **10:50pm** You are in **France** running away from you 5 euro fine in **Germany**. You finish paying your **13** euro bill at the coffee shop. Then when you check your *inbox* at **11:59pm** our lawyer emails the following.

> Hello this Bob your Lawyer your pickpocket lawsuit is favoring you come ASAP.
> In the email there is this attachment:
> [image]

Note: Your lawyer is not fluent in English.

Hint:

> How many vertical boxes are there?

Hint 2:

> Look at the email more closely.

Hint 3:

> Gb fbyir guvf chmmyr lbh trg gur bhgchg sebz jura lbh hfr n npebfgvp pvcure. (gur grkg vf abg gur bayl uvag)

Comment: Where did you get this?

Comment: I made this puzzle myself

Comment: Planning to add any new hints?

Comment: @Techidiot just figured out how to crack it! It has been so long since I created this but I now added a hint. :)